# Flask, concurrent.futures and SQLAlchemy - No application found: work inside a view function or push an application context

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, concurrent.futures

Im building a `Flask` app which require a background process resulting in uploads to a `SQLAlchemy` database.

> Relevant snippets:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import concurrent.futures
import queue
from models import Upload_Tracks

app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app)

app.config.update(
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI= "sqlite:///%s" % os.path.join(app.root_path, 'path/to/player.sqlite3'))

q = queue.Queue()
```

**In `database.py`:**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**In `models.py`:**

```
def Upload_Tracks(item):
        uri = None
        title = unidecode(item['title'])
        artist = unidecode(item['artist'])
        preview = item['preview']
        energy = item['energy']
        popularity = item['popularity']
        tempo = item['tempo']
        brightness = item['brightness']
        key = item['key']
        image = item['artist_image']
        duration = item['duration']
        loudness = item['loudness']
        valence = item['valence']
        genre = item['genre']

        track = Track(title=title,
                      artist=artist,
                      uri=uri,
                      track_id=None)

        db.session.add(track)

        track.preview = preview
        track.energy = energy
        track.popularity = popularity
        track.tempo = tempo
        track.genre = genre
        track.brightness = brightness
        track.key = key
        track.image = image
        track.duration = duration
        track.loudness = loudness
        track.valence = valence

        db.session.commit()
```

**first function:**

```
# 1st background process
def build_cache():
    """
    Build general cache 
    from user's streaming
    """
    tracks_and_features = spotify.query_tracks()

    for item in tracks_and_features:
        q.put(item)

    return "CACHE BUILT"
```

**second:**

```
def upload_cache(track):
    # save to database
    Upload_Tracks(filtered_dataset=track) 

    return "CACHE UPLOADED"
```

**`Flask` view:**

```
#background cache
@app.route('/cache')
def cache():
    # We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        #executor.submit(build_cache)

        # start a future for a thread which sends work in through the queue
        future_to_track = {
            executor.submit(build_cache): 'TRACKER DONE'}

        while future_to_track:
            # check for status of the futures which are currently working
            done, not_done = concurrent.futures.wait(
                                                future_to_track, 
                                                timeout=0.25,
                                                return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED) 

            # if there is incoming work, start a new future
            while not q.empty():

                # fetch a track from the queue
                track = q.get()

                # Start the load operation and mark the future with its TRACK
                future_to_track[executor.submit(upload_cache, track)] = track
            # process any completed futures
            for future in done:
                track = future_to_track[future]
                try:
                    data = future.result()
                except Exception as exc:
                    print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (track, exc))
                else:
                    if track == 'TRACKER DONE':
                        print(data)
                    else:
                        print('%r track is nont uploaded to database') % (track)

                # remove the now completed future
                del future_to_track[future]


    return 'Cacheing playlist in the background...'
```

Database works fine with no threading. However, when I run it all, the following exception is being caught:

> FIRST CACHE BUILT
>   {'brightness': 0.4293608513678877, 'energy': 0.757, 'tempo': 116.494, 'duration': 201013, 'key': 5, 'loudness': -7.607, 'genre': [u'art rock', u'dance rock', u'folk rock', u'mellow gold', u'new wave', u'new wave pop', u'power pop', u'pub rock', u'rock', u'roots rock'], 'valence': 0.435, 'artist': u'Elvis Costello & The Attractions', 'popularity': 14, 'artist_image': u'https://i.scdn.co/image/c14ffeb7855625383c266c9c04faa75516a25503', 'title': u'Poor Napoleon', 'preview': u'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/c0d57fed887ea2dbd7f69c7209adab71671b9e6e?cid=d3b2f7a12362468daa393cf457185973'} generated an exception: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.

but the process, to my knowledge, is running within `@app.route`. how is this out of context? how do I fix this?

Comment: Flask stores its context for each request in thread-local variables, therefore you will get these errors when you're trying to access the Flask global objects (e.g. `current_app`, `request` or `g`) from a different thread. `@app.route` has nothing to do with context, it just registers the view within your app.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? Can you post the traceback?

Comment: in terminal. I get the traceback above for all 3 tracks tested. so it is caught inside the `executor`.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone who meet the same problem

```
from flask import current_app
def context_wrap(fn):
    app_context = current_app.app_context()
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with app_context:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

#Then In this case:
future_to_track = {
        executor.submit(context_wrap(build_cache)): 'TRACKER DONE'}
#OR In your case:
context_wrap(any_func_need_context)
```

Comment: I was trying to update my SQLALchemy database via `add_default_done_callback` using flask-executor and this solution is the only thing that worked!.

Comment: I ran into so many troubles with `flask-executor` but this simple solution did it!!

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
def build_cache():
    with app.app_context():
        (...)

def upload_cache(track):
    with app.app_context():
        (...)

@app.route('/cache')
def cache():
    with app.app_context():
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
            (...)
```

Comment: For what it's work, I created a library to solve this exact problem in flask called Flask-Executor. You can initialise it using common Flask extension configuration patterns, and otherwise use it like a normal executor - don't worry about app contexts or request contexts, all that is managed for you transparently so everything should "just work".